# How to refactor react hooks nested function properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function component which uses two states and both are changed based on event triggered.

I've read on react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) that is a bad idea to change states in nested function or condition. I also seen some examples using useEffects, but I have no clear idea how to properly refactor this.

here is my entire component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import AppHeader from '../app-header'
import AppFooter from '../app-footer'
import SearchInput from '../search-input'
import Stats from '../stats'
import Chart from '../chart'
import { getBundleInfoAPI } from '../../services/hostApi'
import 'react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css'
import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner'

function App() {
  const [isSpinnerVisible, setSpinnerVisible] = useState(false)
  const [bundleData, setBundleData] = useState({})

  const _handleOnItemSelected = (item) => {
    if (item && item.package && item.package.name && item.package.version) {
      setSpinnerVisible(true)
      getBundleInfoAPI(item.package.name, item.package.version)
        .then(resposeData => setBundleData(resposeData))
        .finally(() => setSpinnerVisible(false))
    } else {
      // TODO - implement an error handler component?
      console.warn('WARNING: The selected bundle does not have name or version!')
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <AppHeader />

      <main>
        <SearchInput onItemSelected={_handleOnItemSelected} />

        <div className="app-main-inner-container">
          <Loader type="Triangle" color="#00BFFF" height={200} width={200} visible={isSpinnerVisible} />

          {!isSpinnerVisible &&
            <div className="app-stats-chart-container">
              <section className="app-stats-container"><Stats size={bundleData.stats} /></section>
              <section className="app-chart-container"><Chart bundleChartData={bundleData.chart} /></section>
            </div>
          }
        </div>
      </main>

      <AppFooter />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs section you are referring to means you must not put line with `useState` inside of nested functions, conditions, loops.

Calling setter returned by hook is definitely fine and correct.

Comment: Ok I understand now, but should I create a custom hook for my handler ? (like best practice for readability)

Comment: I'm asking this first, because I just started using hooks and I don't know if nested functions inside components are a good approach :-|

Comment: look for exameple this is another component from the same example project: https://github.com/vsambor/npm-bundle-info/blob/master/client/src/components/search-input/SearchInput.js Does this looks right to you?

Comment: custom hooks are for reusability. once you reuse the same logic across multiple components _and_ that logic involves some hooks like `useState` and `useEffect` then you _may_ consider making custom hook. Otherwise there is no value.

Comment: Ok, I understand the idea to use custom hooks only when used on multiple components. The only problem I can't understand is why nested functions are seen as ok (if so? ) Because to me it looks like at each render it will recreate the functions, so I don't know how optimized is this approach ... :-|

Comment: it's much easier to write, much easier to read and almost the same efficient to recreate callbacks on each render than fight [stale data in closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/).

Answer (score 2):

This is fine, you are showing the loading screen when starting fetch and then hiding it when the fetch is done... no refactoring needed

Comment: I'm not sure though, check this: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: I see but like I said what you are doing is fine, if you don't want to use hooks just call setState directly?

Comment: This is perfectly fine. `useState` hooks are called on the top level and it's nothing wrong with using setter function inside another function.

Comment: I want to use hooks, this is the point. Otherwise I would use classes